# Compare user input to csv file in php console

Tags: php, csv

I'm creating a system that a users can use to see if other users are active or not on a platform. The first part of the code takes the .csv file (data.csv) and put it into an array. I'm encountering an issue with comparing the array to the user input.

Here is the php code

```
<?php
$csvData = file_get_contents("data.csv");
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$a = array();

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $a[] = str_getcsv($line);
}

$user = readline("Enter Username: ");

if (in_array($user,$a)) {
    print_r("good");
}
?>
```

Here is the csv file

```
username,status
TestUser,active
Admin,not-active
```

I've checked the php website and could not find any documentation on this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [`str_getcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) returns an array, so `$a` would hold an array of arrays: https://3v4l.org/8DTgP

Comment: One option, I guess, would be to use `array_column` to grab the first column only, and use `in_array` with that? https://3v4l.org/FhSCh

Answer (score 0):

With [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map) you can do something by looping the array, in a shorter way than foreach.

Also, you should remove the header from the file, otherwise it will be used to check the username.

```
//$csvData = file_get_contents("data.csv");
$csvData = "username,status
TestUser,active
Admin,not-active";

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);

// remove the header line
unset($lines[0]);

// get the values of all lines
$values = array_map(fn($v) => str_getcsv($v, ","), $lines);

// get only usernames
$userNames = array_column($values, "0");

//$user = readline("Enter Username: ");
$user = "MyUser";

if(in_array($user, $userNames)) {
    print("Found.");
}
else {
    print("Not found.");
}
```

You can test it here https://3v4l.org/4CTTg.

Depending on your php version, since 7.4 you can use the [Arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php), a shorter way to declare anonymous function.
For lower versions, use this:

```
$values = array_map(function($v){ return str_getcsv($v, ","); }, $lines);
```